# Visual Odometry with Realsense Camera

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, ros-kinetic, realsense-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement a visual odometry package with my Intel Realsense camera. Is there a way to implement stereo visual odometry with this camera since the depth is calculated with infrared sensors? I am using [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros) package and the realsense package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290640/visual-odometry-with-realsense-camera/) by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2018-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two very mature packages I'm aware of that implement both visual odometry and SLAM using depth cameras such as the realsense. [Rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) and [rgbdslam](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam), both of these work with the 3D information that is produced by the realsense.

You don't need to perform your own stereopsis calculations with the Realsense, they calculate depth themselves in a different way.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on 2018-05-08**:
That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!